# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object-Laravel5-ConversationsController.php

Tags: php, laravel-5

hello everyone I have a big problem in the show function. I do not know what the problem is .. I get this error "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

ConversationController.php

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Repository\ConversationRepository;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager;


class ConversationsController extends Controller
{

private $r;
private $auth;

    public function __construct(ConversationRepository $conversationRepository, AuthManager $auth){
        $this->r= $conversationRepository;
        $this->auth=$auth;
    }

    public function index () {

        return  view('conversations/index' , ['users'=> $this->r->getConversations($this->auth->user()->id)]);

    }
    public function show (User $user) {
        return  view('conversations/show',[
            'users'=> $this->r->getConversations($this->auth->user()->id),
             'user' => $user
             ]) ;

    }

    public function store(User $user){
        $this->r->createMessage(
            $request->get('content'),
            $this->auth->user()->id,
            $user->id

        );
        return redirect(route('conversations.show', ['id'=> $user->id]));
    }
}
?>
```

web.php

```html
<?php

//use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'ConversationsController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/conversations', 'ConversationsController@index')->name('conversations');
Route::get('/conversations/{user}', 'ConversationsController@show')->name('conversations.show');
Route::post('/conversations/{user}', 'ConversationsController@store');
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suZss.png)ConversationRepository.php

```html
<?php
namespace App\Repository;

use App\User;
use App\Message;



class ConversationRepository {

    private $user;
    private $message;

    public function __construct(User $user, Message $message){
        $this ->user = $user;
        $this->message= $message;
    }

    public function getConversations(int $userId){
        return $this->user->newQuery()
        ->select('name', 'id')
        ->where('id', '!=', $userId)
        ->get();

    }

    public function createMessage (string $content, int $from, int $to){
        return $this->message->newQuery()-> create([
            'content' => $content,
            'from_id' => $from,
            'to' => $to,
            'created_at' => Carbon::now()
        ]);
    }
}
?>
```

the problem in this function

```html
 public function show (User $user) {
        return  view('conversations/show',[
            'users'=> $this->r->getConversations($this->auth->user()->id),
             'user' => $user
             ]) ;
```

more precisely in this line

```
'users'=> $this->r->getConversations($this->auth->user()->id)
```

And thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$this->auth()->user()->id` instead. Also the routes accessing `auth` should be enclosed within the `web` middleware.